# Running functions in kivy extremely frequently (Kivy Clock/FreeClock)

Tags: python, bluetooth, kivy, clock

I am working on an app that takes in data from a Bluetooth device (that I handle simply through the serial module). That I know how to do. But giving it a new life in Kivy - displaying it - creates a problem of everything being synced with FPS. I want to run the function all the time in the background, hundreds of times a second. It's fair to say that out of 10000 incoming packets 10 might be useful. So if I would go by clock scheduling it would have to be (well) under 20 ms per cycle.
**Simply put:** *how do I run one of the functions separately from the FPS? Is there a clean way of using the Free version of the clock for only one function and how is that achieved?*
I want a simple solution, I can reinvent the wheel, but I don't want to.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `threading` for this.
Here is a little example of using `threading` with kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
import threading
import time

Builder.load_string('''

<MyLayout>:
    Label:
        text: str(root.data)
''')


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    data = NumericProperty(0)
    count = 0
    running = True

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.after_init)

    def after_init(self, dt):
        threading.Thread(target=self.func).start()

    def func(self):
        while self.running:
            self.data += 1
            time.sleep(0.1)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = MyLayout()
        return self.root

    def on_stop(self):
        self.root.running = False

MyApp().run()
```